# What is an "inner isomorphism" between different groups?

Tags: group-theory, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

It is well known that if $X$ is a path-connected topological space containing points $x$ and $y$, then the fundamental groups $\pi_1(X,x)$ and $\pi_1(X,y)$ are isomorphic. [Wikipedia makes](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Fundamental_group&oldid=648590804) the further claim that the two groups are not only identical up to isomorphism but "actually even up to *inner* isomorphism".

What does "inner isomorphism" mean here? I know what an inner *automorphism* is, but here the elements of the groups are different objects (homotopy classes of closed paths that begin and end at $x$, versus ditto at $y$), so automorphisms are definitely not on the table.

The obvious isomorphism(s) does arise by fixing a path $\alpha$ from $y$ to $x$ and considering the map
$$[\gamma]\in\pi_1(X,x)\mapsto [\alpha+\gamma-\alpha]\in\pi_1(X,y)$$
which does look at bit like conjugation with $\alpha$ -- but (a) $\alpha$ lives *outside* either group so I'm not quite prepared to call that "inner", and (b) this seems to be very specific to the case of fundamental groups.

Is the remark in Wikipedia simply nonsense, or is there a relevant technical meaning of "inner isomorphism"? Googling didn't seem to uncover one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference between "up to isomorphism" and "up to unique isomorphism" is that in the former case the isomorphism is not guaranteed to be unique. In general, if $X, Y$ are two isomorphic objects, two isomorphisms between them differ by an element of $\text{Aut}(Y)$.

"Up to inner isomorphism" can then be interpreted to mean the following (although I find it a strange way to put it). The only "meaningful" isomorphisms between fundamental groups at two basepoints are those that arise from paths between basepoints. Two such isomorphisms don't differ by an arbitrary element of the automorphism group; in fact they are guaranteed to differ by at worst an arbitrary element of the inner automorphism group.

Here is how I would prefer to say things. There is a very familiar category of groups and group homomorphisms $\text{Grp}$ that we all know and love, as well as a very familiar functor from pointed topological spaces to this category, namely the fundamental group functor.

There is also a 2-category of groups that is maybe less familiar: it's the category of groups, group homomorphisms, and natural transformations between group homomorphisms regarded as functors between one-object categories. Very explicitly, if $G, H$ are two groups, then a 2-morphism between two morphisms $f, g : G \to H$ is an element $h \in H$ such that $f(x) = h g(x) h^{-1}$.

This 2-category has a homotopy category $\text{Ho}(\text{Grp})$ which is *not* the category of groups and group homomorphisms; it's the category of groups and conjugacy classes of group homomorphisms. Now the claim is that

> The fundamental group functor, viewed as a functor on path-connected but *unpointed* spaces, naturally takes values in $\text{Ho}(\text{Grp})$.

In fact $\text{Ho}(\text{Grp})$ is equivalent to the homotopy category of classifying spaces $BG$ where $G$ is discrete, and the above functor restricts to such an equivalence. The 2-category of groups is in turn equivalent to the homotopy 2-category of classifying spaces $BG$, continuous maps between them, and homotopy classes of homotopies between them. The ordinary category of groups is the homotopy category of *pointed* classifying spaces.

The punchline is that you can make sense of what a "group up to inner isomorphism" is: it's an object in $\text{Ho}(\text{Grp})$. Many groups in nature are in fact only groups up to inner isomorphism in this sense, such as the absolute Galois group of a field. (To make it a group you need to pick a "basepoint," or equivalently an algebraic closure.) This is one way of making precise the common intuition in number theory that in some sense the only meaningful information you can extract from Galois groups is conjugacy-invariant information, e.g. characters of representations.

For example, "underlying set" does not define a functor $\text{Ho}(\text{Grp}) \to \text{Set}$. An approximation is the functor $\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}, -)$, which returns the conjugacy classes.

Comment: Inner automorphism has a very specific meaning in group theory. How does your answer relate to that meaning?

Comment: @Rob: it comes from the conjugacy actions that define the 2-morphisms above.

Comment: so please give me the definition of an "inner isomorphism" between two groups.

Comment: @Rob: an inner isomorphism between two groups is an isomorphism in $\text{Ho}(\text{Grp})$. (This doesn't tell you anything about how to produce inner isomorphisms that's different from how you produce ordinary isomorphisms, but it tells you what it means for two inner isomorphisms to be the same or not: they're the same if, regarded as ordinary isomorphisms, they're conjugate via an inner automorphism of the target. Admittedly, this definition clashes with the usual definition of "inner automorphism," but it does make the statement the OP is interested in meaningfully true.)

Comment: Anyway, like I said, I find the term "inner isomorphism" strange and it's not how I would put it, but there is content in the claim the OP is interested in and it does have something to do with conjugation. Your claim that the statement doesn't make any sense is too strong.

Comment: @Qiachu Yuan: the OP is talking about what the Wikipedia says (and, I think it is nonsense). But thanks for expanding my thinking about this!

Comment: Interesting. I get a bit lost at "this 2-category has a homotopy category"; do you have a reference for what that means?

Comment: @Henning: I just mean you identify two 1-morphisms if they're isomorphic via an invertible 2-morphism. (It's the same construction you do to get the homotopy category of spaces.) I spelled out more explicitly what this category is later in the answer: groups and conjugacy classes of group homomorphisms.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Ah, that makes sense. (If I understand correctly, to get Toph we would start with a 2-category of topological spaces, continuous maps and equivalence classes of homotopies?)

Comment: Further question: When you say in the indented thesis that the functor $\rm Top_{pathconnected}\to Ho(Grp)$ is "natural", are you implying there is a natural transformation around somewhere? We'd need two different functors between the same two categories for that, and I can't quite imagine what they would be ...

Comment: @Henning: no, I just mean natural in the colloquial sense. There isn't a fundamental group functor to groups, because of the lack of a basepoint, but a natural way to deal with that is to pass to the homotopy category of groups instead, which resolves precisely the ambiguity that the lack of a basepoint introduces but no more. (Arguably an even more natural thing to do is to take a functor to the homotopy category of *connected groupoids*, but people are scared of groupoids and in any case this is equivalent to the homotopy category of groups.)

Comment: And here I thought it was a category-theoretic credo that "natural" in the colloquial sense always corresponds to the technical sense. :D

Answer (score 3):

This can be stated in a more rigorous way. In particular, for any two homotopy classes $[q], [p]$ from $x$ to $y$ (that is, they start at $x$ and end at $y$), they induce isomorphisms on the fundamental group. Namely, if $\ell$ is a loop at $x$, then $p^{-1}\ell p$ is a loop at $y$. (Similarly for $q$).

We can relate the isomorphisms as follows.

$$ [p^{-1} \ell p] = [p^{-1} q q^{-1} \ell q q^{-1} q p] = [p^{-1}q][q^{-1}\ell q][p^{-1}q]^{-1},$$
but where now we see that $[p^{-1}q]$ is a loop, and so is in the group. So they really are the same up to conjugation by an element of the group, and hence inner automorphism.

Comment: [I think. I haven't thought about these things in a long time. I could certainly be wrong]

Comment: We don't need $[p]$ to be an element of the group, since we're not conjugating by $[p]$. We're conjugating by $[p^{-1}q]$, which is part of the group.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, what you're saying is that if we construct two _different_ isomorphisms $\pi_1(X,x)\to\pi_1(X,y)$ in the way of the well-known proof, they will be related by an inner automorphism in (either) one of the groups. I agree with that, but notice that this is not in general the case for two _arbitrary_ isomorphisms $\pi_1(X,x)\to\pi_1(X,y)$.

Comment: Heh, did you take this from (7) [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.00231.pdf)? If so, our google-fus are equivalent up to isomorphism (perhaps up to inner isomorphism).

Comment: I suppose one could say that in the category where the objects are groups and the morphisms are classes of homomorphisms modulo inner automorphism at either end (is that even a category? I'm not quite sure) there is a _canonical_ isomorphism between $\pi_1(X,x)$ and $\pi_2(X,y)$.

Comment: @anon Yes - our google-fus must be equivalent. Some judicious use of quotes, inner isomorphism, and fundamental group.

Comment: @Henning: yes, that's a category. See my answer for details.

Comment: The middle term in your equation has a spurious extra factor $q$ (before the final $p$) - unfortunately, this is too small an edit for me to make.

Answer (score 3):

Let $G$ be any groupoid. There is an ${\rm Aut}$ functor $G\to{\rm Grp}$, so that any arrow $x\to y$ induces an isomorphism ${\rm Aut}(x)\to{\rm Aut}(y)$. Of course there exist pairs of group homomorphisms

$$\phi:{\rm Aut}(x)\to {\rm Aut}(y) \\ \psi:{\rm Aut}(y)\to{\rm Aut}(x)$$

such that $\psi\circ\phi\not\in{\rm Inn}({\rm Aut}(x))$ or $\phi\circ\psi\not\in{\rm Inn}({\rm Aut}(y))$ *in general*, **but** if $\phi$ and $\psi$ are images of morphisms $x\to y$ and $y\to x$ (respectively) in $G$ then $\psi\circ\phi$ and $\phi\circ\psi$ *are* both inner.

I believe the above is the idea behind "inner" isomorphisms. (Perhaps we could generalize it to any collection of isomorphisms of groups such that any automorphism composed from them is inner.) Here we are applying this idea to the fundamental groupoid $\Pi(X)$, which is a category whose objects are points $x\in X$ and whose morphisms are homotopy classes of paths $x\to y$.

Comment: Yes, but what the wikipedia page says (about fundamental groups, not fundamental groupoids) is just wrong.

Comment: @Rob The question at hand is what the author of that remark is even *saying* in the first place. The remark does not have any standard interpretation I'm aware of, so this is my understanding of the most likely articulation of what the author was thinking while writing it.

Comment: the question at hand is the meaning of the term "inner isomorphism". I don't believe this term has any well-known definition. And I believe the wikipedia entry is sloppy in using the term without defining it.

Comment: @RobArthan Right.

Comment: This is interesting anyway -- I didn't know (or remember) the concept of groupoid. To connect it to the Wikipedia comment, one might say that this presents an additional perspective on "groupoid": a groupoid can be thought of as a collection of groups _together_ with an internally consistent choice of which isomorphisms between them we want to call "inner", such that the "inner" isomorphisms from a group to itself are exactly the inner automorphisms of that group. (That is, in the same sense a "topological space" is a set together with a choice of which subsets we want to call "open").

Answer (score 0):

"inner isomorphism" has no agreed meaning and I don't think it is a useful term to use in the wikipedia article. An inner automorphism $f: G \rightarrow G$ of a group is one that is given by conjugation by a group element ($f(x) = g^{-1}xg$, for some element $g$ of $G$).

Comment: I agree with your comment that Wikipedia was sloppy, that the term is not standard, and the author should have defined it. But I take "just doesn't make sense in the context of this statement" to suggest that no plausible and valuable meaning for the statement can be extracted from the context, which I think is false. I am not the one who downvoted however.

Comment: @anon: no worries. I've reworded my answer in a way that may perhaps make it less objectionable to the down-voter. I would love to know what the down-voter's objection was.